# Количество делителей n-значного числа (n>20), задаваемого строкой

Tags: c++

Нужно найти количество делителей n-значного числа (n > 20). Как это реализовать?

Comment: Используя длинную арифметику.

Comment: В общем случае - никак. Особенно когда n очень велико.

Comment: @Harry , можно алгоритм? Я смотрел длинную арифметику для деления, но она не понятна, так как делим столбиком. Но если таким образом искать количество делителей у двадцатизначного числа, то работа программы займет очень много времени

Comment: А по-другому пока что никак. Если бы можно было быстро раскладывать очень большие числа на множители, то шифрование RSA тут же приказало бы долго жить... Вы дайте хоть какие-то ограничения сверху - а то как знать, может, у вас вообще миллион цифр в числе...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1 Можете изучить длинную арифметику. Например, [здесь](http://e-maxx.ru/algo/big_integer) или [здесь](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_ei-SpjitN4).

2 Можете использовать готовую длинную арифметику. Например, [MPIR](http://mpir.org) или [GMP](http://gmplib.org/)

Ну а дальше делаете перебор по всем простым числам, в надежде, что это будет работать быстро. В худшем случае это будет работать... несколько миллиардов лет.

UPD: Вот, кстати, случайное 21-значное простое число для проверки `235910232262849857961`

Comment: А, не, в худшем случае это будет работать бесконечно долго... `n>20`...

Comment: оставлю тут эти ссылки http://e-maxx.ru/algo/factorization http://e-maxx.ru/algo/bpsw